# Angualr HttpClient get response it not correct?

Tags: angular, get, angular-httpclient

I stumbled across a very weird behavior on HttpClient.get. I am trying to figure this out by myself for an eternity, but it  does not make sense to me.
I am requesting an array of pretty complex objects but on the clientside some properties are missing, which are sent by the server and even visible in Chrome DevTools Network Tab.

Missing values appear on user => jobApplication[] => updates[].

Here is my method to get objects

```
    async getRelevantUsers(showError = true): Promise<User[]> {
        const reply = await this.http.get<any>((isDevMode() ? serverConstants.devServerUrl : serverConstants.prodServerUrl) + 'user/relevant', this.requestOptions).pipe(catchError((err, caught) => {
            console.log(err);
            return new Promise(resolve => {
                resolve(undefined);
            });
        })).toPromise();
        if (reply) {
            console.log(reply);
            return reply;
        }
        return undefined;
    }
```

Here the response in Chrome DevTools network Tab for a specific user from the list (Postman shows the same outcome):

[image]

The following image shows the response of the same user from the `console.log(...)` point of view in the method i posted here. Why is there only one element in the array `updates` instead of multiple like sent by the server? It does not get manipulated by myself, where is the problem?

[image]

Angular appends only the last update with id 19 ?? why

Comment: Might we worth checking the output in Postman, it will help you narrow down the problem to client or server side.

Comment: Thanks but in postman it is exactly the same outcome like in the chrome devtools network tab. There I get the right amount of `updates`. It ist just in the client itself, in angular, where the problem appears

Comment: try to add a console log in the pipe for the http call .. .pipe(tap(console.log)) .. that output should match to chrome tools -> network tab

Comment: @maxkart I tried it but the output does not match with devtools network tab. They match with console.log from the method

Comment: very strange indeed .. do you have any angular http interceptor in your application ..?? thats the only other thing which I can think of could impacting the data

Comment: @maxkart No i am not using any interceptor.  :(

Comment: Do the other users have a similar problem ?

Comment: I figured it out but it still appears to be weird. Turns out a childcomponent manipulated the a variable which got  the response as a reference. But there is like 100 steps between the request and said manipulation. I also expected it would not affect console.log but obviously console.log gets called after all these steps..